# Hero Card Buttons PostBack

Tags: c#, botframework

I am making use of Hero Cards in Bot Framework v4. I do not want to show any value whenever a button from a Hero Card is clicked. Because of that, the type of the `CardAction` is set to PostBack. Unfortunately, the first time a button is clicked in a chat the value is shown in the form. If I click the same button again it is not showing any value anymore.

Let me know how to disable showing it the first time.

Code of the button of the Hero Card:

```
CardAction plButton = new CardAction()
{
   Title = "Connect to Employee",
   Value = "Connect",
   Type = ActionTypes.PostBack
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the BotFramework Emulator? This was a [bug](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator/issues/1140) that has now been fixed in the latest version of the emulator. An update should fix it.